# Spring Integration: call service when flow completes

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Spring Itegration (5.0.2) flow that reads data from an HTTP endpoint and publish Kafka messages using the (split) data from the HTTP response.

I would like to execute a "*final*" action before the flow completes, some sort of "try, catch, finally" but I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve this.
This is my code:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow startFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> new GenericMessage<>(""),
  c -> c.id("flow1")
    .poller(
      Pollers.fixedDelay(period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, initialDelay).taskExecutor(taskExecutor)))

  .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://....)
     .charset("UTF-8")
    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET))
  .transform(new transformer())
  .split()
  .channel(CHANNEL_1)
  .controlBus()
  .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow toKafka(KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate) {
return IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_1)

  .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
    // KAFKA SPECIFIC
  .get();
}
```

Essentially, when all the messages have been sent (note that I'm using `.split`), I need to call a Spring bean to update some data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about "when all the messages" after splitter, then you need to take a look into an `.aggregate()`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator.

The splitter populates special `sequence details` headers into each splitted item and an aggregator is able to gather them to a single entity by default using those headers from received message.

Since you talk about the process after sending to Kafka, you should make your `CHANNEL_1` as a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and have the mentioned `.aggregate()` as the last subscriber to this channel. The service to update some data should be already after this aggregator.

Comment: gotcha, thanks. I was looking at `aggregate` but I was missing the `PublishSubscribeChannel` part. Thanks!